# Opening vector layer via URI with spaces

Tags: qgis, geojson, rest, uri

I try to open a [Pelias](https://github.com/pelias/docker/) REST API link that returns GeoJSON with add vector layer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Maj</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) in QGIS.

If i try `http://localhost:4000/v1/search?text=belgium`, it's ok.
If i try `http://localhost:4000/v1/search?text=Place De Brouckère, belgium`, it does not.

Because of spaces in the link or maybe multiple features?

[image]

Comment: You always must to encode your URI when you have special characters in it. https://www.urlencoder.org/

Comment: ok, i encoded it but it does not solve the problem. Same critical error:
2020-05-19T14:18:31     CRITICAL    Source de données non valide : http://localhost%3A4000%2Fv1%2Fsearch%3Ftext%3DPlace%20De%20Brouck%C3%A8re%2C%20belgium n'est pas une source de données valide ou reconnue.

Comment: Try just the URL parameter value part: `http://localhost:4000/v1/search?text=Place%20De%20Brouck%C3%A8re%2C%20belgium`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to format correctly your url, like that :

[image: QGIS]

Comment: i tried, but not better. Do you use pelias too? q= is not a parameter